PDF XeTeX Preview is not working in latest lyx in MacOS
OS: Sequoia 15.2
Latex: MacTex latest
LyX: 2.4.2.1


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you have Document > Settings > Fonts > Use system fonts checked?

@scottosty It works
